# Using corcel to add a category to a post

Tags: php, laravel, corcel

I am using ["jgrossi/corcel": "3.0.0"](https://github.com/corcel/corcel), `Laravel 6.16.0` and `PHP 7.4.1`

I would like to add an existing category `Product` to my new post in wordpress. However, I am not sure how to do this.

I can create a wordpress post the following way:

```
        $post = new Post();
        $post->post_title = $title;
        $post->post_content = $msg;
        $post->save();
```

Any suggestions how to use `corcel` to add an existing category to the post?

Appreciate your replies!

Comment: `I would like to add an existing category Product to my new post` not understood what does category means in this respect do you need a new model, column etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Post model has a belongsToMany relationship to the taxonomies model, as you can see here...

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function taxonomies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Taxonomy::class,
        'term_relationships',
        'object_id',
        'term_taxonomy_id'
    );
}

//Source: https://github.com/corcel/corcel/blob/5.0/src/Model/Post.php
//Lines: 185-196
```

Therefore you should be able to link the post to a category using the category id like so...

```
$post->taxonomies()->associate($taxonomyId);
```

You can find more about these types of relationships here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships